# my balloon pop up doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, popup, asp.net-ajax

I am using a pop up but it cant show any thing in final render.
Can any body tell me what is wrong in my cods:
Thank you very much
Here is my code:
 panel cod:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
<b>   Test.</b>
 </asp:Panel>
```

balloon pop up code:

```
<asp:BalloonPopupExtender ID="len_BalloonPopupExtender" runat="server" BalloonPopupControlID="Panel1"

CustomCssUrl="" DisplayOnClick="False" DisplayOnMouseOver="True" DynamicServicePath=""

Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" TargetControlID="len" DisplayOnFocus="False"

BalloonStyle="Rectangle">

</asp:BalloonPopupExtender>
```

textbox code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="len" onmouseout="this.BalloonPopupControlBehavior.hidePopup();" runat="server" BorderColor="#3399FF" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="2px" Width="50"  AutoPostBack="true" TabIndex="2" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

And one more thing is that i use `<asp:BalloonPopupExtender>` not `<Ajax:BalloonPopupExtender>` one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifying `BalloonPopupControlID="Panel1"`, but your panel id is **Panel2**.

Just change it to the correct value and it will work:

[image]